# Keyboard not working or stuck on a key

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, 17.04, hibernate

I am a laptop user. Sometimes the keyboard is not working or stuck on a key(like pressing 'f' or 't' etc. forever). Sometimes this is happening while typing the password on login page and sometimes it happens after being logged in. Mostly it happens when switching OS Windows 10 to Ubuntu when I restart my PC. When I put Ubuntu to *sleep mode* and then wake it up, the keyboard rarely works. Generally it is not happening when turning off the PC and then on again.

Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 17.04

By the way same issues for different Linux distro like

- Mint 18.2 (Cinnemon)
- openSuse 42.2 (it happends switched kde to gnome)
- fedora 26

My Computer is a *Monster Abra A5 V5.1 with Intel i7-4720HQ*.

Comment: It's a hardware problem. Clean your keyboard. Do NOT use soap and water.

Comment: its %100 software problem. For a year it is happening  on linux distros but on windows it is never happened